# firebase functions still dont work after i verified my billing stuff

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

when I try deploying my app this outputs:

> Error: Your project quiz-byte must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command. Required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete. To upgrade, visit the following URL:

I did verify my billing options, but they keep asking me to pay for their paid plan.

Am I supposed to wait some time or something?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo I haven't but i moved to render, way simpler then firebase.